# Выбор экземпляра класса из списка по свойству этого экземпляра

Tags: python, классы, список

Существует некоторый класс пользователя `User`, который является дочерним классом класса службы пользователей `UserCore`. Информация о пользователях хранится в `JSON`-файлах, которые читаются при помощи  функции в классе службы системы пользователей, затем эта функция создаёт экземпляр класса пользователя на основании данных, прочитанных из `JSON` и заталкивает его в список `users`.

Класс `User` имеет, среди прочего, логический атрибут `current`, который присваивается экземпляру класса пользователя во время события входа в систему и отбирается при выходе.

После того, как событие входа в систему произошло и атрибут `current` присвоен текущему экземпляру пользователя, нужно удалить из списка `users` все экземпляры класса пользователя, не имеющие положительного атрибута `current`. Как это сделать?

Я знал, что для этого нужно создать копию списка, при создании выбрав те экземпляры, что подлежат удалению,  и поробовал сделать списковое включение:

```py
    def cleanUserList(self, core):

        self.checker = [(not User.current) for User in self.users]
        print(self.checker) # проверям выполнение команды

Вывод: [False, True]
```

Моё списковое включение вместо списка всех экземпляров класса `User` с отрицательным `current` выводит мне исходный список со значениями атрибутов `current` всех экземпляров подряд. Как правильно сделать нужное мне списковое включение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так можно отобрать нужных пользователей:

```
[User for User in self.users if User.current>0]
```